# How to find an object on certain coordinates in java

Tags: java, swing, object, find, coordinates

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java and I'm trying to find a way to see if an object is located on certain coordinates. I've tried to search for similar questions, but I still haven't found an answer.

The program I'm working on is a map (image file) and the user should be able to create places and place them on the map (which will be displayed as triangles on the map). There is also this function where the user should be able to type in coordinates to see if there already is a place on those coordinates.

The object is an object of the class "Place" and consists a name, an x-coordinate and an y-coordinate.

Here is my code:

```
class CoordinatesListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {

        try {
            CoordinatesForm c = new CoordinatesForm();
            int answer = c.getAnswer();

            if (answer != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                return;
            }
            if (c.getPosition() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input kkk", "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Position p = c.getPosition();
                boolean flag = false;
                for (Position key : positionList.keySet()) {
                    if (key.getXCoordinate() == p.getXCoordinate() && key.getYCoordinate() == p.getYCoordinate()) {
                        flag = true;
                        this.setAllMarkedPlacesUnMarked();
                        Place place = positionList.get(key);
                        if (place != null) {
                            System.out.println("the place " + place + "against position " + key);
                            place.setMarked(true);
                            if (!place.isVisible()) {
                                place.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            markedPlacesHashMap.put(place.getName(), place);
                            if (markedPlacesHashMap.containsKey(place.getName())) {
                                markedPlacesHashMap.get(place.getName()).add(place);
                            } else {
                                //   ArrayList<Place> newMarkedPlaces = new ArrayList<>();
                                // newMarkedPlaces.add(place);
                                markedPlacesHashMap.put(place.getName(), place);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Also, when a place is created, the user shouldn't be able to place another place on the same coordinates. There should be an error message saying that a place already exists on those coordinates.

Here is the code where a place is created:

```
private void createNamedPlace(int x, int y, String answer) {
    Position pos = new Position(x, y);
    display.add(n = new NamedPlace(selectedCategory, pos, answer));
    p = n;
    places = new ArrayList<>();
    placeByCategory = new ArrayList<>();

positionList.put(pos, n);

    if (categoryMap.containsKey(selectedCategory)) {
        categoryMap.get(selectedCategory).add(n);
        if (nameList.containsKey(answer)) {
            nameList.get(answer).add(n);
        } else {
            places.add(n);
            nameList.put(answer, places);
        }
    } else {
        placeByCategory.add(n);
        categoryMap.put(selectedCategory, placeByCategory);
        if (nameList.containsKey(answer)) {
            nameList.get(answer).add(n);
            System.out.println("The new Place have been added in the Name 
            List, the place name is :" + answer);
            this.displayMap(nameList, " PlACES LIST BY NAME");
        } else {
            places.add(n);
            nameList.put(answer, places);
this.displayMap(nameList, "PLACES LIST BY NAME");
        }
        this.displayMap(categoryMap, " PlACES LIST BY CATEGORY");
    }
    n.addMouseListener(new TriangleListener());
    display.validate();
    display.repaint();
    display.removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
    display.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    newButton.setEnabled(true);
    categoryList.clearSelection();
    isSaved = false;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a problem description we can help with. Read [mcve] and enhance your question. Then: avoid doing so many things in a listener. You better create helper classes / methods.

Comment: Try creating a simple example to reproduce the issue, without all of this other (potentially unrelated) code. Creating a minimal example for reproducing the issue makes it much easier for others to help you with debugging the issue, but it's also a useful step in your own debugging: you may find that the error is obvious to you when you have a more simple example.

Answer (score 0):

All Swing components are ultimately derived from the `Component` class, which has a method `getBounds()`, returning a rectangle.  So you can simply write something like

```
if (myComponent.getBounds().contains(x,y)) {
    // do something
```

where `x` and `y` are the co-ordinates of the point you're trying to check.